# Convert linear audio frequency distribution to logarithmic/perceptual distribution?

Tags: math, audio, logarithm, beep

I am creating some audio cues for scripts, and keep running into the same problem:

Human perception is logarithmic.  If I want to cut a range of sounds into 10 equal parts, I can't just subtract the lowest pitch from the highest pitch and divide by 10. Those steps will not be perceptually accurate.

So, when dealing with a function that gives output in the 20-20000 range (kHz), is there a basic mathematical function that *reasonably approximates* a conversion of these numbers to their perceptual equivalents -- while still mapping in the 20-20000 range?

Example:

I am dealing with a "beep" command which takes kHz as a range.

I know from my own system testing that the functional range for this command on the system being tested is 38 to 9900Hz.

So if I was creating an audio countdown to go through 100 items, I would divide 9900-38 / 100 into a 98.62Hz range per item.  If I were to create an audio countdown, I would simply create a sequence of beeps starting at max range, decreasing 98.62Hz per beep.

But this doesn't sound perceptually accurate.  Most time is spent in high-sounding frequencies.  Not enough time is spent in low-sounding frequencies.

I did manage to fix this for my white noise generator, but I can't apply that same kind of fix to an audio countdown. (Mainly because there is quite the leeway for mistakes in a  white noise generator.) In that instance, I simply divided by Hz by 10. But I did so randomly. It gave me the desired effect, but not any kind of consistent mapping function:

```
        if  %@RANDOM[1,10] gt 6 (set BEEP_FREQUENCY_TEMP=%@FLOOR[%@EVAL[BEEP_FREQUENCY_TEMP / 10]] 
        if  %@RANDOM[1,10] gt 9 (set BEEP_FREQUENCY_TEMP=%@FLOOR[%@EVAL[BEEP_FREQUENCY_TEMP / 10]] 
        if  %@RANDOM[1,10] gt 8 (set BEEP_FREQUENCY_TEMP=%@FLOOR[%@EVAL[BEEP_FREQUENCY_TEMP / 10]]
```

Can you tell I don't even know how to ask my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up looking up a list of all frequencies that match notes, making a text file that has a lit of all those frequencies, and simply iterating through that at whatever interval I want.  For example, if I want a note that indicates 10% upload progress, it takes the total number of lines, and grabs the line that is 10% through the file.  This solved the problem of making my audio countdowns *sound* linear even though the frequencies required to do this aren't linear.

A lookup table.

Not elegant, but works.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a logarithmic spacing:

```
// start - start frequency
// stop - stop frequency
// n - the point which you wish to compute (zero based)
// N - the number of points over which to divide the frequency
// range.
double logspace(double start, double stop, int n, int N)
{
    return start * pow(stop/start, n/(double)(N-1));
}
```

for example:

```
logspace(20, 200000, 0, 4) = 20
logspace(20, 200000, 1, 4) = 200
logspace(20, 200000, 2, 4) = 2000
logspace(20, 200000, 3, 4) = 20000
```

Beware that `logspace(x,y,0,N)` may not exactly equal `x` and `logspace(x,y,N-1,N)` may not exactly equal `y`. This is due to floating point precision and rounding errors.

Answer (score 0):

As you may know, going from one tone to the one an octave higher doubles its frequency. Going from there one more octave doubles again. So what you have is a linear increase (by 1 per octave, or 1/12 per semitone) in the exponent in a base-two exponential:

f = 440Hz · 2<sup>x</sup>

Now divide the range of possible x values into regular intervals and you should be done. To turn frequency f to pitch x you need to compute a logarithm, namely

x = log<sub>2</sub>(f / 440Hz) = ln(f / 440Hz)/ln(2)